# Bug comes while searching user, it shows 0 points or if i have upvoted then it shows the given vote point as reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, user-search

Bug comes while Searching User, all user's reputation is 0, 
it shows reputation which I had up-voted today to that user

[image: While Searching User, i up-voted his answer so it shows 10 otherwise it was 0 when show first]

[image: In Profile]

Comment: and this only happens while searching user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reputation 95 is what you see in the profile page is for all the time he/she scored.

In the search page, you see the 10 reputation is for the **week**'s reputation only. See the red circled place in the screenshot.

[image: Week's reputation]

Also you can filter in the month, quarter, year wise reputations.

When you filter by all time, the reputation will match with the same in the profile page.

[image]

Comment: +3 for Freehand red circles, -1 for one non-complying freehand circle ...